# Proper -std with 'decltype(auto)' and how to change -std with Cmake

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, makefile, c++14

I'm working with two libraries:

- the first one uses   -std=c++11
- the second one uses  -std=c++1y

Now, I created a test case in the first library (because it was simpler here) in which I use the header files of both libraries. When I compile using

> make

For the lines with

> decltype (auto) ...

I get these two error messages:

> error: expected primary-expression before 'auto'
>
> error: expected unqualified-id before 'decltype'

These lines are from some .cpp files of the second library and when I compile examples of the second library (which are defined inside it) these errors does not appear. So I believe that the solution is to change -std=c++11 of the first library to -std=c++1y since is the only difference for the flags between the two libraries.

Assuming that my idea could be correct... clearly inside the first library there are a lot of CMake files inside the source directory and I'm a bit afraid to change the configurations before everything does not work. Moreover I did not install the library, a person installed it for me. Generally where could I find CXX_FLAGS variables? And after adding -std=c++14, should I re-install the library or will be enough a 'make' where I compile my test case?

I'm aware that probably many informations are missing, but this is the first time I work on CMake with complex libraries.

Comment: decltype(auto) is part of the C++14 and not C++11. Thus, rightfully you get error when compiling with -std=c++11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your libraries are already compiled, you need to enable c++14 features for your test project. The simple way to do this is to just add the `-std=c++1y` or `-std=c++14` (depending on your compiler) to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable using `cmake-gui` (or through command-line `ccmake`).

A better approach though is to use cmake's `target_compile_features` command (see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html) for documentation). It lets you define the features that you want to use in your code and CMake sets the compiler flags accordingly. So in your case, add `target_compile_features(mylib cxx_decltype_auto)` command in your `CMakeLists.txt` file (where `mylib` is the name of your target that you added using `add_library` or `add_executable`).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you compile both libraries and then your exe

```
add_library(libA ...)
target_compile_features(libA
    PUBLIC
        # Or whatever the features that the headers of this one needs
        cxx_variadic_templates
)

add_library(libB ...)
target_compile_features(libB
    PUBLIC cxx_decltype_auto
)

add_executable(myexe ...)
# CMake will compute the correct flag to use.
target_link_libraries(myexe libA libB)
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html

See: [What INTERFACE, PUBLIC, PRIVATE mean in cmake target compilation setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981602/what-interface-public-private-mean-in-cmake-target-compilation-setting)